# What is the syntax for setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, audio, syntax, settimeout

What is the syntax for `setTimeout()`? I can't get it to work.

I have two functions:

```
audioPlayer.pause();
audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
```

How do I add a settimeout so it executes after for example 2000ms? I've tried:

```
setTimeout('audioPlayer.pause()',1500);
setTimeout('audioPlayer.currentTime = 0',1500);
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function(){audioPlayer.pause()},2000)
setTimeout(function(){audioPlayer.currentTime = 0},2000)
```

http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/dom/methods/setTimeout
EDIT: [MDN on setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout)